# Is there a way to move a frame directly to userspace?

Tags: networking, ethernet, linux-kernel

When receiving an Ethernet frame,It goes kernel protocol stack(TCP/IP) first,after,it goes to userspace.... I want to implement userspace stack...My operating system is Linux(Ubuntu/Parrot sec)....Is there a way to move the Ethernet frame to userspace directly without using kernel protocol stack?Is there a possible solution using tap devices...?

EX:
Using PF_PACKET,SOCK_RAW,if dns query(raw) is sent(not listening the ports,only bind to interface),after receiving the dns response(it can be sniffed),kernel will send port unreachable icmp packet to dns server...(because there is not application listing on port 53)That can be prevented using iptables but,it is not a good solution...then,is there a way to direct frame to userspace without going to kernel stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a number of ways to bypass the kernel and implement the complete network stack in userspace. [This article](https://blog.cloudflare.com/kernel-bypass/) mentions five of them: PACKET_MMAP, PF_RING, Snabbswitch, DPDK, Netmap.

These are typically used by big companies that need really fast network processing, faster than the kernel can provide. The investment to write your own networking stack is substantial, and probably too much for a single person.

If you use tap devices, you are basically writing a simulated network card, and you can see the frames as if they would go to this virtual card - after passing through the kernel network stack. Vice versa, you give the kernel frames as they would be received on the wire, so the kernel can pass them through the network stack.

This is easily doable by a single person, and depending on what your actual goal is (you didn't say, so this is likely an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)), this might do what you want.

Comment: One of my goals is handling many connections at same time.Using AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM ,I want wait for completion of 3 way handshake.Really,I want handle them asynchronously.....Ex:As a client, when syn packet was sent using raw sockets(PF_PACKET),after,receiving syn-ack ,kernel send rst packets,that can be prevented using a iptable rule..but,it is not a good solution...(There is not a listing port related to packet in the system,only socket bind to Ethernet interface ).I tried that using 2 threads(main thread for sending packet , a daemon thread for sniffing)...

Comment: Please edit your question with this additional information. How many connections do you want to handle at the same time? Hundreds? Millions? And for this purpose, you'll probably really need to rewrite the complete network stack.

Comment: Millions... but,problem is not the rewriting the network stack(it can be implemented in userspace but,not all protocols)....problem is the preventing use of kernel protocol stack automatically ...(when receiving a frame to interface it automatically goes to kernel protocol stack)

Comment: The solutions mentioned in the article bypass the kernel.